# login and sign up buttons in the header in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

here I have a problem in the logic for logging in and the sign up button.

So the problem is, when the user is logged in, the login and sign up buttons disappear. and replaced with a "back" button

[image]

**but that's what makes me confused because I don't know how to make the logic conditions**,

Maybe someone here can help me. Thank you

Code =

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Link from "next/link";
import styles from "./Header.module.scss";

import { IoMenu } from "react-icons/io5";
import MainLogo from "../../public/images/logo/logo_blend.svg";
import MainLogoFill from "../../public/images/logo/logo_fill.svg";

import { Button, ButtonContainer } from "../global/Button";
import Language from "../global/Language";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const Header = ({ isResponsive, setOpen, isLandingQuiz,style }) => {
  const [isTop, setTop] = useState(true);
  const router = useRouter()
  
  const onScroll = (value) => {
    if(isLandingQuiz === true){
      if(router.pathname === "/preview-store/store"){
        window.location.href = "/quiz";
      }else{
        const element = document.getElementById(value);
        element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start" });
      }
    }else{
      if (router.pathname === "/article") {
        window.location.href = "/";
      } else {
        const element = document.getElementById(value);
        element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start" });
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const onScroll = () => {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
            setTop(false);
        } else {
            setTop(true);
        }
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    return function cleanup() {
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    };
}, []);

  return (
    <header
      className={isLandingQuiz === true ? styles.container + (isResponsive ? " " + styles.mobile : "") : styles.containerLanding + (isResponsive ? " " + styles.mobile : "")}
      style={{
        background: !isTop && "#fff",
        boxShadow: !isTop && "0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)",
        style
      }}
    >
      <div className={styles.header}>
        {isLandingQuiz === false ? 
        <>
         {isResponsive && (
          <IoMenu
            onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
            className={styles.menu_button}
            style={{ color: !isTop && "#313466" }}
          />
        )}
        <div className={styles.logo} style={{ color: !isTop && "#313466" }}>
          <Link href="/">{isTop ? <MainLogo /> : <MainLogoFill />}</Link>
        </div>
        {!isResponsive && (
          <div className={styles.menu} style={{ color: !isTop && "#313466" }}>
            <li onClick={() => onScroll(1)} className={styles.sub_menu}>
              <a> About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li onClick={() => onScroll(2)} className={styles.sub_menu}>
              Feature
            </li>
            <li onClick={() => onScroll(3)} className={styles.sub_menu}>
              Survey Example
            </li>
            <Link href="/article" className={styles.sub_menu}>
              <a>Article</a>
            </Link>
          </div>
        )}
        <Language
          isReverse={!isTop}
          className={styles.language}
          isMini={isResponsive}
        />
        {!isResponsive && (
          <ButtonContainer style={{ height: "2.25rem", flex: 0 }}>
            <Link href="/register">
              <a>
                <Button style={{ width: "6.5rem" }}>SIGN UP</Button>
              </a>
            </Link>
            <Link href="/login">
              <a>
                <Button
                  style={{ width: "6.5rem", color: isTop && "#fff" }}
                  isTransparent
                >
                  LOGIN
                </Button>
              </a>
            </Link>
          </ButtonContainer>
        )}
        </>
        
        :
        <>
         {isResponsive && (
          <IoMenu
            onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
            className={styles.menu_button}
            style={{ color: !isTop && "#313466" }}
          />
        )}
        <div className={styles.logo} style={{ color: !isTop && "#313466" }}>
          <Link href="/">{isTop ? <MainLogo /> : <MainLogoFill />}</Link>
        </div>
        {!isResponsive && (
          <div className={styles.menu} style={{ color: !isTop && "#313466" }}>
            <li className={styles.sub_menu} onClick={() => onScroll(1)}>
              <a> About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li className={styles.sub_menu} onClick={() => onScroll(2)}>
              Feature
            </li>
            <Link 
               href={{
                pathname: "/preview-store/store",
                query: { type: 'quiz' },
              }}
            className={styles.sub_menu}>
              <a>Bank Soal</a>
            </Link>
          </div>
        )}
        <Language
          isReverse={!isTop}
          className={styles.language}
          isMini={isResponsive}
        />
        {!isResponsive && (
          <ButtonContainer style={{ height: "2.25rem", flex: 0 }}>
            <Link href="/register">
              <a>
                <Button style={{ width: "6.5rem" }}>SIGN UP</Button>
              </a>
            </Link>
            <Link href="/login">
              <a>
                <Button
                  style={{ width: "6.5rem", color: isTop && "#fff" }}
                  isTransparent
                >
                  LOGIN
                </Button>
              </a>
            </Link>
          </ButtonContainer>
        )}
        </>
        
        }
       
      </div>
    </header>
  );
};

Header.propTypes = {
  isResponsive: PropTypes.bool,
  setOpen: PropTypes.func,
  isLandingQuiz: PropTypes.bool,
  style: PropTypes.object
};

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you don't know how to access the variable that shows if a user is logged in or not.

There are so many ways to do this, But first you need to learn and apply concepts of authentication & authorization yourself (been there, its kinda hard but you can make it :D).

Nevertheless, I will tell you the basics.

Usually, you are going to access a cookie called "access_token". if the user is "logged in" the access_token cookie will contain some string (i.e Ah932dMas97SAa327r.....).

You can directly access the cookie like:

```
const accessToken = readCookie("access_token") //Ah932dMas97SAa327r.....
```

or put the cookie value in a state management thing (i.e. redux)

I cannot give you a code example because the scope is too large. You need to make your own auth system using something like firebase auth, auth0, Fusion Auth, Ory kratos, or just use something like next-auth. But in the end, what you need to do is get the access_token value and just do a simple conditional on it.

I hope this helps!